# After vfork(), how does the linker resolve execve() without clobbering parent memory?

Tags: c, linker, glibc, got, vfork

If the `execve@plt` contains the stub that calls into the linker, is the process of resolving the address of `execve` guaranteed to not modify any of the parent's memory ?

Comment: What bad things could possibly happen if the plt stub of the parent process is modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the execve@plt contains the stub that calls into the linker

It doesn't call into the (staic) linker. It calls into the runtime loader (aka dynamic linker).

> is the process of resolving the address of execve guaranteed to not modify any of the parent's memory ?

On the contrary: it *will* update the processes' GOT table<sup>1</sup>, before calling the `execve` system call wrapper in `libc.so.6`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Assuming lazy PLT resolution is in effect and `execve` has not already been resolved.

Comment: I don't think this takes into account the use of `vfork` rather than regular `fork`.